# Returning a file within a json object in Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a Scala function that sends back a file to the front end using:

```
def sendMefile(id: String, template: String) = Action { request =>
    val file = convert(latexDir, id, template)
    Ok.sendFile(file)
}
```

In this function file becomes a pdf file that I need to send to the front end. However, now I am being asked to send back a json object that for the front end will look like this:

```
 {'id':id, 'file':file}
```

there is something similar at:

[Scala Play upload file within a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982817/scala-play-upload-file-within-a-form)

but I don't think I can use this solution (as I was asked to send the json).

Comment: There's no way to do this. HTTP doesn't let you produce (or consume) this.

Comment: Put the `id` in the response header (but be careful with this... headers can be modified en-route) or use a `multipart/form-data` response.